# How to add or remove class name from element with other classes while having more than 1 instance of the same element

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I'm having trouble with adding or removing CSS class name from element.
It seems that it not add class, its overwrite any other classes may be.

```
<div class="my-div class-a"></div>
```

I would like in code to add `class-b` to this div.

```
thisDivElement.className = 'class-b';
```

this will remove `my-div class-a` and instead paste `class-b`.

```
<div class="class-b"></div>
```

So how in angular2 you add/remove classes without overitte other classes. Please advice for the right way doing that.

Comment: Important! keep in mind element has more than 1 instance. I want to add/remove class from specific element

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the angular docs:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

You can modify which classes are active by replacing the true/false values with variables that you set in code.

e.g.
HTML:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': firstClassActive, 'second': secondClassActive, 'third': thirdClassActive}">...</some-element>
```

Typescript:

```
export class AppComponent {
  firstClassActive: boolean = true;
  secondClassActive: boolean = false;
  thirdClassActive: boolean = false;
}
```

More detailed examples here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html

I should also point out that you could do this using jQuery, which will give you more direct access to DOM elements - but you would *in my opinion* be better off sticking with Angular template binding.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not mentioned something important. If my div has more than one instance in my template and I want to change only particular one

Comment: Depending on how many divs you're talking about, if its not too many then I would suggest you create variables for each div so that you can control them separately.
If you have a lot of divs to control, then you probably want to create a sub-component for each one, with an input parameter so that you can set their values from the parent component.